# Need to divide an input by 52 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My developer is currently on annual leave and I need to work out how to make a change to some code.

The form input is a salary and I am able to output this salary using:

```
$('#demo').html($('#salary').val());
```

This displays within `<div id="demo"></div>`

I need to display the salary input as weekly (salary / 52).

Any assistance on how this can be achieved is appreciated.

I believed it to be:

```
$('#demo').html($('#salary'/52).val());
```

But this does not work.

Comment: `$('#demo').html($('#salary').val()/52);`

Comment: I would look into converting the .val() to a float then divide by 52 and use some kind of precision. Or else your displayed value might not be correct.

Comment: Side note: A year has more than 52 weeks (about 52.143, but be aware of leap years). If you actually pay people a weekly (or 4-weekly) salary, I would store and display that. If you have an annual or monthly salary, be careful with divisions like this, or you may get complaints from your employees.

Comment: To add rounding: `$("#demo").text(($("#salaray").val()/52).toFixed(2))`

Comment: This would be a $('#demo').html($('#salary').val() / 52);

Comment: @RyanWilson the act of `/52` will convert it to a float.  If it's not a float, yes, you'll get an error, but you'll get an error with other "conversions" if not careful, eg `parseFloat("1,234") == 1` ... handy :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Agreed. I think you would be best served doing the parse checking on the value before doing any math, but I see what you are saying. I was alluding to using parseFloat() / 52 with toFixed() as you showed in your comment

Answer (score 3):

In your example :

`$('#demo').html($('#salary'/52).val());`

you are trying to add the division to the jQuery selector. that won't work.

you will need to make sure the result of the selector is a `number` and then divide that by 52:

`$('#demo').html(parseFloat($('#salary').val())/52);`

Comment: (keep in mind that the `parseFloat` is already implied by the division, so you could just do `$('#demo').html($('#salary').val()/52);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#demo').html($('#salary').val()/52);
```

Comment: `.val()` returns a string, but apparently that's fine because JS is weird and `"104"/52 === 2`...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com). You first should get value with:

`$('#salary').val(); //get value`

After divide:

`$('#salary').val() / 52`

It is a simple programming logic. After you are able to set your value in any place, like:

`$('#demo').html($('#salary').val()/52);`

Comment: `.val()` returns a string.

Comment: @JeremyThille Javascript isn't strongly typed, so there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Ah right, Javascript's weirdness, where `"104"/52 === 2` :/

Comment: @JeremyThille jQuery is not typed :)

Comment: jQuery is not a language either :)

Comment: He needs just put the result in a div, why convert ? I understand you, but i think that is not necessary in this scenario, that's why I put the documentation link.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add the division to the jQuery selector. that's Wrong.

```
$('#demo').html($('#salary'/52).val());
```

You need to make Sure first you get value of Salary then divide it into week. and it will return as **string**, so you have to make to **Integer** OR **Float**

Float :

```
$('#demo').html(parseFloat($('#salary').val())/52);
```

Integer :

```
$('#demo').html(parseInt($('#salary').val())/52);
```